# How to wrap two line into single line with delimiter

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have executed below command

```
cat /proc/loadavg && date
```

Actual Result:

```
0.00 0.00 0.00 1/803 26256
Fri Aug 26 09:00:56 EEST 2016
```

Expected Result:

```
0.00 0.00 0.00 1/803 26256 @@ Fri Aug 26 09:00:56 EEST 2016
```

I have tried `sed` and `tr` , but didn't work.

```
cat /proc/loadavg && date | sed 's/\n/ @@ /g'

cat /proc/loadavg && date | tr '\n' ' @@ '
```

Any idea, what I am missing?

Comment: I think `sed` removes the `\n` before it loads the line in the pattern space , then puts it back when it prints the pattern space to output, so you cant do a substtution on it in sed.

Comment: just got a strike, based on answers, ``echo "`cat /proc/loadavg` @@ `date`"``.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `printf`. You have two strings and you want to output them with some additional formatting.  That's exactly what `printf` does.

```
$ printf "%s @@ %s\n" "$(cat /proc/loadavg)" "$(date)"
```

Your `tr` attempt does not work since `tr` modifies *characters*, not words. You could use it to replace the newlines with one single character though:

```
$ ( cat /proc/loadavg; date ) | tr '\n' '@'
```

... but it doesn't do quite what you need.

Your `sed` attempt does not work since the newline is stripped from the input to `sed` (i.e. `sed -n '/\n/p' inputfile` would never print anything).

You could still do it with `sed` if you read the second line (from `date`) with the `N` editing command while editing the first line (which *will* place a newline between them):

```
$ ( cat /proc/loadavg; date ) | sed 'N;s/\n/ @@ /'
```

... but I would personally prefer the `printf` solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
echo `cat /proc/loadavg` @@ `date`
```

Comment: There are plenty of good answers already and yours has a bug causing `@@` to show up between each word.

Comment: Fixed by removing xargs and printf complexity.

Comment: Now that is a good simple solution.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
( cat /proc/loadavg && date ) | sed 'N; s/\n/ @@ /'
```

First, your attempts don't work because the pipe `|` applies only to `date`, not no both command.  To work around that you need to run `cat ... && date` in a subshell, and then redirect the subshell's `stdout`.

Then `tr '\n' ' @@ '` doesn't work because you can't replace a character with multiple characters.

And `sed 's/\n/ @@ /g'` doesn't work because `sed` only gets to see lines one at a time.  To get it to see newlines you need to merge both lines of input in the same buffer.  Which is what `N` does above.

Comment: this worked for me. to expand a little more on  `sed`'s  `N` command. `n` prints the pattern space to output and pulls the next line into the pattern space - like sed would have done anyway. The `N` command pulls the next line into the pattern space but *doesn't* print the pattern, so you end up with both lines in the pattern space, which is why the substitution `s/\n/ @@ /` works

Answer (score 3):

This might help you,

```
( cat /proc/loadavg && date ) | awk 'ORS=" @@ "'
```

Comment: Note that your `printf` command will use the output from `cat` and `date` as a formatting string... If any part of those outputs contains a `%` formatting specifier, it will cause an error.

Comment: you didnt need to delete the `printf` command, per Kusalananda's comment, you could group the output into a separate arguments, i.e. `printf <format_string> <string> <string>`

Answer (score 2):

Just for something different...

```
(cat /proc/loadavg && date) | paste -d@ - - | sed 's/@/ @@ /'
```

`paste -d@ - -` pastes the two line side-by-side with "@" in-between. Then sed replaces the single "@" with " @@ "

Comment: OK. for the record, you can do without `sed` e.g.  `( cat /proc/loadavg && date ) | paste -d' @@ ' - /dev/null /dev/null /dev/null -`

Answer (score 1):

The extra filtering you are doing to remove the new line is only being applied to the `date` command, therefore try

```
{ cat /proc/loadavg && date; } | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
export DELIMITER=' @@ '; cat /proc/loadavg | tr -d '\n'; echo -n "$DELIMITER" && date
```

Output: `0.34 0.39 0.40 1/1065 29353 @@ Fr 26. Aug 09:30:26 CEST 2016`

It only removes the newline after the line output by cat, then echoes a delimiter string without a newline (-n) and finally appends the output of date.